# TikZ: Labeled point

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm currently doing:

```
\node [label=below:crimson]     (crimson) at (0.1,-0.9)   {}; 
\draw [fill=black] (crimson) circle (1pt);
```

Is there a way of doing this in one command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
\node [label=below:crimson,draw,fill=black,circle,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt] at (0.1,-0.9) {};
```

Comment: AFAIK another possibility is to use plot marks like `\draw plot [mark=o]`. Have a look at the `pgfmanual`.